# What is the number of strings satisfying the following constraints?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

We need to make a string of size $n$. Each character of the string is either ‘R’, ‘B’ or ‘G’. In the final string there needs to be at least r number of ‘R’, at least b number of ‘B’ and at least g number of ‘G’ (such that r + g + b <= n).

How to find the number of such constrained strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let we count for first the number $N_{x,y,z}$ of constrained strings in which there are $x\geq r$ characters 'R', $y \geq g$ characters 'G' and $z\geq b$ characters 'B', with $x+y+z=n$. We have:
$$ N_{x,y,z} = \binom{n}{x}\binom{n-x}{y}\binom{n-x-y}{z}=\frac{n!}{x!y!z!},$$
hence the total number of constrained strings is given by:
$$n!\sum_{\substack{x\geq r,y\geq g,z\geq b \\ x+y+z=n}}\frac{1}{x!y!z!}.$$

Comment: Since $\frac{n!}{x!y!z!}=\binom{n}{x,y,z}$ is just the standard trinomial, probably easier to just leave it in that form rather than factoring out the common $n!$ term.